# Can't download generated .ics-file in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, icalendar

I've generated a ics-file via my php script which allows me to download a .ics-file in Safari (6.0.2) but in Chrome (23.0.1271.101) and Firefox (17.0.1) I get an error message:

> Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.

The .ics-file is valid (checked with two separate sources) and I can open it in iCal. I've followed scripts and tips on both this forum and many others.

This is the code that generates the .ics-file:

```php
        $tz_sthlm = new DateTimeZone( 'Europe/Stockholm' );
        $tz_utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
        $dateEvent = new DateTime( $event->datetime, $tz_sthlm );
        $dateEvent->setTimezone( $tz_utc );

        $filename = str_replace('/', '-', $event->webblink);

        $output = '';

        $output .= 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n";
        $output .= 'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n";
        $output .= 'PRODID:-//Medicinska Foreningen Orebro//Biljettbokning//SV-SE' . "\r\n";
        $output .= 'METHOD:PUBLISH' . "\r\n";
        $output .= 'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n";
        $output .= 'CLASS:PUBLIC' . "\r\n";
        $output .= 'CREATED:' . date('Ymd\THis') . "\r\n";

        $description = strip_tags( htmlspecialchars_decode( $event->description ) );
        $description = str_replace(array( "\n", ';' ), array( '\n', '\;' ), $description);

        $output .= 'DESCRIPTION:' . $description . "\r\n";
        $output .= 'DTSTART:' . $dateEvent->format('Ymd\THis\Z') . "\r\n";
        $dateEvent->modify('+4 hour');
        $output .= 'DTEND:' . $dateEvent->format( 'Ymd\THis\Z' ) . "\r\n";
        $output .= 'DTSTAMP:' . $dateEvent->format('Ymd\THis\Z') . "\r\n";
        $output .= 'LAST-MODIFIED:' . date('Ymd\THis') . "\r\n";
        $output .= 'LOCATION:' . $event->location . "\r\n";
        $output .= 'UID:' . $dateEvent->format('Ymd\THis') . '-' . md5( $event->title ) . '@' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "\r\n";
        $output .= 'END:VEVENT' . "\r\n";
        $output .= 'END:VCALENDAR';

        header("Content-Type: text/Calendar;charset=utf-8");
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '.ics"');
/*      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: -1');
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . mb_strlen( $output, '8bit' ) );
    */
        echo $output;
        exit;
```

This is the output

```
 BEGIN:VCALENDAR
 VERSION:2.0
 PRODID:-//My Company//SV-SE
 METHOD:PUBLISH
 BEGIN:VEVENT
 CLASS:PUBLIC
 CREATED:20130105T000547
 DESCRIPTION:This is my description.
 DTSTART:20130124T170000Z
 DTEND:20130124T210000Z
 DTSTAMP:20130124T210000Z
 LAST-MODIFIED:20130105T000547
 LOCATION:Top secret
 UID:20130124T210000-c88f2fb3f033284ec886aa15acb9eaee@example.com
 END:VEVENT
 END:VCALENDAR
```

Any ideas to why I get and error message in Chrome and Firefox?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `Content-Disposition: attachment` instead of `inline`? That's what the PHP documentation for `header` suggests, I've never bothered to read the header specification.

Comment: Reading [RFC 2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt), it looks like Content-Disposition doesn't make a lot of sense in an HTTP context. Still, I think that `attachment` makes more sense than `inline` for the case where you want to force a download. That said, I can't say if this is really the problem you have right now. I don't have PHP on this machine to test.

Comment: Unfortunately, `attachment` made no difference. Still the same error.

Comment: @user1941689 without sending any headers, does the file correctly output to browser screen for Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: @cryptic Yes, it does in both browsers.

Comment: @user1941689 us there any way you can link us to the file so we can test on our end under different browsers?

Comment: @cryptic Sure, http://www.mforebro.se/biljetter/events/2013/psykvard/ics/ with the headers, http://www.mforebro.se/biljetter/events/2013/psykvard/ics/?noheaders without.

Comment: @user1941689, try below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the file is sending a 404 header status try putting this header:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK', true, 200);
```